# Preencher Sessão PHP via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

Estou com uma dificuldade para resolver um problema.

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP que precisa preencher umas sessões

Estou utilizando esse método para mandar.

```
<script src="localhost:8080/painel_cop_mdu/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function carregaFiltro(){
    $('#filtrar').load('filtros.php');  
}
 function addFiltro(botao,selecao) {     
             $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "filtrando.php", 
                    data: {botao : botao,selecao : selecao},
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("tudo ocorreu bem!");
                    },
                    error: function() {
             alert("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar os dados.");
           }                    
                });
          }
function pegaSelect(nomedoselect){

    var options = document.getElementById(nomedoselect).getElementsByTagName("option");
    var texto = "";
    for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
        if(options[i].selected){            
            texto = texto+","+options[i].value;
        }
    }       
    return texto;
}
</script>
<?php
    echo $_SESSION["condicaoRegional"];
?>
</div>
<div id="combos">
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data>
        <div id="dCidades">

            <label>Selecione uma regional</label>
            <select id="cidades" name="cidades[]" size="3" multiple>
            <?php
                regionais();
             ?> 
            </select>    
            <button id="filtrarCidade" onClick="addFiltro('filtrarCidade',pegaSelect('cidades'))" >filtrarNatureza</button>
        </div>
        <div id="dGrupos">
            <label for="">Seelecione um grupo</label>
            <td><select id="grupos" name="grupos[]" size="3" multiple>
             <?php
                grupos($_SESSION["condicaoRegional"]);
             ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="filtrarGrupo" value="filtrarGrupo" onClick="carregaFiltro"/>
        </div>
            <div id="dSub">
            <label for="">Filtrar por sub cluster</label>
            <select id="sub" name="sub[]" size="3" multiple>
                <?php
                sub_cluster($_SESSION["condicaoGrupo"]);
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="filtrarSub" value="filtrarSub" onClick="carregaFiltro" />
        </div>
        <div id="dNatureza">
            <label for="">Filtrar por Natureza</label>
            <select id="natureza" name="natureza[]" size="3" multiple>
                <?php
                cidades($_SESSION["condicaoSubCluster"]);
                ?>
            </select>     
             <button id="filtrarNatureza" onClick="addFiltro('filtrarNatureza',pegaSelect('natureza'))" >filtrarNatureza</button>
         </div>         
        <input type="submit" name="filtrar" value="filtrar" />
        <input type="submit" name="limpar filtros" value="limpar filtros" />
    </form>
</div>
```

e no meu PHP

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include('conexao.php');
  $id = $_POST['botao'];
  $texto = $_POST['selecao'];
  $sql = "insert into obs_painel values (9999,'".$texto."');";  
  $conn->query($sql);
  $_SESSION["condicaoRegional"] =  $_POST['selecao'];
?>
```

No entanto a sessão não é preenchida e também não me retorna nenhum erro.

---

#### Edit

Fiz uma alteração no no arquivo **filtrando.php** e coloquei ele para fazer um *insert* no banco e o mesmo não o faz. Aparentemente ele não esta acessando a página.

coloquei o codigo completo das duas paginas

Comment: @DanielOmine verifico tanto por `select` que carrega depois dessa função quanto quando eu mando imprimir o conteudo da sessão

Comment: Tem certeza que está chamando essa página ? Abra o console do navegador, vá na aba XHR. Clique no botão que chama essa função e veja se a página é invocada.

Comment: @Gumball ele so carrega a propria pagina e folha de estilo

Comment: @DanielOmine eu coloquei o codigo completo das duas paginas mas a questão banco nem é relevante fiz apenas para ter certeza que ele não estava chamando a pagina

Comment: Nesse trecho `alert("tudo ocorreu bem!");`, modifique assim: `console.log("tudo ocorreu bem!", data);`

Comment: E no filtrando.php, na primeira linha, antes do `session_start();`, coloque isso `echo 'OK'; exit;`. Dá um F5 na página do formulário e envie a requisição ajax. Deve mostrar no console do browser tudo `ocorreu bem! OK`. Isso é apenas para debugar e eliminar dúvidas. Entenda a lógica de depuração e conseguirá encontrar o problema.

Comment: @DanielOmine desculpe a demora em responder, fiz o teste mesmo assim não consegui obter nenhuma resposta, como era um projeto que demandava uma certa urgencia acabei refazendo ele em asp.net onde tinha um dominio maior mas mesmo vou seguir testando para ver se consigo achar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Se no seu arquivo possui só esse código:

```
$id = $_POST['botao'];
$texto = $_POST['selecao'];
$_SESSION["condicaoRegional"] = $texto;
```

Esta faltando dar um start na sessão, antes de poder usá-la. Faça assim:

```
session_start();
$id = $_POST['botao'];
$texto = $_POST['selecao'];
$_SESSION["condicaoRegional"] = $texto;
```

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: não deu certo aparentemente não esta enviando para a pagina fiz uma alteração para fazer uma inserção no banco e ate mesmo disparar um alert e não deu certo

Comment: Coloque ali então, como ficou o arquivo que recebe os dados...

Comment: inseri o codigo completo das duas paginas a que faz o envio e a que recebe